# TAdvStringGrid filter CheckUnCheckAll

Tags: delphi, filter, delphi-xe

I can't find any solution to this problem anywhere. Maybe you can help me out.
I am working on a project in Delphi and i'm using the TAdvStringGrid extension.
The autofilter did great work and i managed to find out how to get checkboxes to filter the grid.
My problem is now: How is it possible to clear every filter that is set and uncheck all the checkboxes. I found a parameter called "FilterDropDownCheckUnCheckAll". Sounds great to me. But i just can't figure out how to use this thing.

Anyone who know how this UnCheckAll parameter works ?

Thank you !

Comment: Anywhere?  Surely, the first thing to do would be to ask TMS?

Comment: You can't find it anywhere, including TMS Support Forums?

Comment: Sure, I could send them a Support request. But maybe someone here knows it and answers faster than the TMS Support Team

Comment: Ok, but bear in mind that qs here that show no signs of research or other effort on the part of the asker tend not to get sympathetic responses and often get down-voted, which can have consequences if it happens too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no solution for this problem in the curren TMS String grid version (answer from TMS support in Max 2014)

Answer (score 1):

On TAdvStringGrid version 7.9.0.3 there's a public method "RemoveAllFilters" which does the trick. There's an indirect reference to it in the Developer's Guide pdf. I sympathize with the OP though. TMS documentation is not always the easiest.

Case in point:

> **grid.FilterDropDownCheckUnCheckAll: Boolean** 
>   When true, the option is added to the filter dropdown to immediately check or uncheck all items in the filter dropdown.

This property is a STRING type not a BOOLEAN. It appears it become active when you assign some string to the property, otherwise, it behaves roughly as described.